# run make pattern rule more than once

Tags: makefile

According to the make documentation, pattern rules with multiple outputs run only once while normal rules may run multiple times. I'd like to run pattern rules multiple times to share a recipe. I know I can share them by using a define but that comes with a different set of problems.

I am using gnu make version 3.8.1

This is the makefile I'd like to use. Is there a way to have it run the pattern rule four times?

```
build: test.a.x test.a.y test.b.x test.b.y

clean:
    rm -f test.a.x test.a.y test.b.x test.b.y

%.a.x: optAB=a
%.a.x: optXY=x
%.a.y: optAB=a
%.a.y: optXY=y
%.b.x: optAB=b
%.b.x: optXY=x
%.b.y: optAB=b
%.b.y: optXY=y

%.a.x %.a.y %.b.x %.b.y: %.v
    @echo optAB: $(optAB) optXY: $(optXY) $@ $<
    touch $@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant line in [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro) is

> If a pattern rule has multiple targets, make knows that the rule's recipe is responsible for making all of the targets.

So one way to get around this would be to define multiple targets.  One way to achieve this is to use foreach/eval/call:

```
build: test.a.x test.a.y test.b.x test.b.y

clean:
    rm -f test.a.x test.a.y test.b.x test.b.y

%.a.x: optAB=a
%.a.x: optXY=x
%.a.y: optAB=a
%.a.y: optXY=y
%.b.x: optAB=b
%.b.x: optXY=x
%.b.y: optAB=b
%.b.y: optXY=y

optset1 = a b
optset2 = x y

define target_template
%.$(1).$(2): %.v
    @echo optAB: $$(optAB) optXY: $$(optXY) $$@ $$<
    touch $$@

endef

$(foreach opt1,$(optset1),$(foreach opt2,$(optset2),$(eval $(call target_template,$(opt1),$(opt2)))))
```

We define a template for the rule, and then call/eval that template for each of the options, to generate multiple rules, one for each target.  Note the `$$` in the template definition are to ensure the variables are not expanded when the template is defined, but only when it is evaluated to generate each target.

Comment: Thanks! I don't like the fact that I have to use $$ because emacs does not color the template correctly, but the technique works great.